# Как пофиксить слишком высокую температуру видеокарты при старте SFML игры?

Tags: c++, sfml

Написал игру на языке SFML!
Когда игра включена, моей видеокарте плохо (доходит от 37 градусов до 57)
Как пофиксить?

Comment: Ну это еще не так плохо.

Comment: Можно ли уменьшить?
Пробовал использовать sf::Time и sf::Clock, но игра становиться похожа на какашку при использовании этих атрибутов!

Comment: Лучше охлаждайте карту.

Comment: С видюхой всё ок

Comment: не парься... всё что до 70°C — норма... до 80°C — допустимо много...

Comment: У меня на старой видеокарте при старте приложений с SFML еще и дросселя свистели, так что ты легко отделался. А вообще, включи вертикальную синхронизацию. `window.setVerticalSyncEnabled(true)`

Comment: А мне наоборот отключение вертикальной синхронизации помогало (если вместо нее ограничивать FPS sleep-ом).